# Issue using "System.IO.Ports" namespace on Xamarin.Mac 2.0

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I'm trying to add the namespace System.IO.Ports into my Xamarin.Mac project, but it's not working. Anyone who has the same issue ?Also I see that in my Project.csproj file, the  is the V2.0, but on the Xamarin.Mac documentation it says that in the 3.0 version we can have this namespace. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Update your project to 3.0

Comment: Do you know how to do that @Jason ?

Comment: I imagine there's a setting in the project properties dialog

Comment: I've tried searching on the project properties but there's nothing regarding the upgrade @Jason

Comment: 1. Honestly, when I tried to change the `TargetFrameworkVersion` from v2.0 to v3.0 and tried to reload the project, however, it failed to reload, see [Update Project Type & Build Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-mac-apps#1-update-project-type--build-target) 2. Xamarin.Mac2.0 represents the Unified API, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/update-xamarinmac-apps/